# Azure Powershell - Not able to add Subnet Settings to Database

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network, subnet

I am trying to add a subnet to SQL Server using Azure Az Module. The command I am using is

`New-AzSqlServerVirtualNetworkRule -VirtualNetworkRuleName "newvnetrule1" -ServerName $sqlServer.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $sqlServer.ResourceGroupName -VirtualNetworkSubnetId $newsubnetId -ErrorAction Stop`

I get an exception saying:

`The client with object id does not have permission to perform this action`

The object id belong to a SPN of name `Azure SQL Virtual Network to Network Resource Provider`.

I get the exact same issue while provisioning cosmos db account with ARM template only this time the erroneous SPN is `Azure Cosmos DB Virtual Network to Network Resource Provider`

Can anyone throw some light on this? The same code used to work fine. All the services are registered for the subnet too

Comment: Could you please check if the user or service principal you use to login Azure has enough permissions or his RABC role? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/check-access

Comment: Hi yes the SPN I am using is the owner of the subscription

Answer (score 1):

The `Owner` role is enough, I test it on my side, it works fine.

```
$virtualNetworkSubnetId = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/joynet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/joysqlnet/subnets/default"

New-AzSqlServerVirtualNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName joynet -ServerName joyser -VirtualNetworkRuleName vnetrule1 -VirtualNetworkSubnetId $virtualNetworkSubnetId
```

[image]

---

To fix the issue, try to use `Clear-AzContext` to clear all the local account information, then use the script below to login again.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<Application ID>"
$azureTenantId= "<Tenant ID>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<Client secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

Then run `(Get-AzContext).Account`, make sure the `Id` is the same as the `Application ID` of the service principal you are using, also the `Tenant ID` of the service principal should be the same as the GUID in `Tenants`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will check again!

Comment: Yes I tried the above steps but nothing worked. Eventually we ended up assigning new role assignment to the scope mentioned in error details. The problematic SPNs were default ones created by MS Azure itself. Thanks for your time though on this.

Comment: @Garima So the problematic service principal does not have the Owner role previously? If so, I think my reply is right. No matter where the SP comes from, it always needs the role to do operations.

Comment: @Garima If it is helpful, could you accept it as answer?:-)